# Memcpy leading to block freed twice error

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, std, memcpy

I have a map which I am filling as needed. To get the contents of the map out into another variable I am using memcpy.

If the memcpy line is commented, I see the output print correctly displayed.
100 => 1234 Fruits

If I uncomment the memcpy, I see the below error. The previously seen print does not get displayed as well.

block freed twice

Exited: ExitFailure 127

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct apple
{
    int iValue;
    std::string str1;
};

typedef std::map<int, apple> AppleMap;

int main()
{
    AppleMap one;
    apple structaa;
    structaa.iValue = 1234;
    structaa.str1 = "Fruits";
    int value = 100;
    one[value]=structaa;

    AppleMap::iterator it = one.find(100);
    if(it != one.end())
    {
        std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second.iValue << '\t' << it->second.str1 << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Value Not Found\n";
    }

    apple structbb; 
    memcpy(&structbb, &(it->second), sizeof(apple));

    return 0;
}
```

Any help on what I have done wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't even be using memcpy in this context. Use assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not copy a "deep" structure (such as `apple`) using `memcpy`.  The reason why your `apple` struct is deep is because it contains a `std::string` which has memory on the heap. When you use `memcpy` to copy `std::string` you are duplicating the pointer to the heap, but now you have two structs (one `structbb` and one inside the map pointing to the same memory on the heap.

The proper thing to do is just copy `structbb` directly and don't use `memcpy`, ie

```
structbb = it->second;
```

This will use a default copy method, which will copy each member using *their* defined copy methods. The default copy method for the string member `str1` is safe, meaning that the copied string points to a *new* heap memory location, so that the old string can be safely destroyed without affecting the new string.

You will also want to move this line inside the protection of your `if(it != one.end()` block. Otherwise if you get "value not Found", `it->second` will be bogus.

Answer (score 1):

Internally, `std::string` stores a pointer to heap memory.

When you copy an `apple` to another `apple` with `std::copy`, the `std::string` in the copied-to struct will contain a pointer to the same memory location as the `std::string` in the copied-from struct.

Thus, when the structs get destroyed, both `std::string`s will try to free the same memory. That's why you get the "block freed twice" error.

The solution, as pointed out by [Paul R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/253056/paul-r) in the comments, is to use assignment which will properly handle the copying of an `std::string`:

```
apple structbb = it->second;
```